# how to tune this query to get the last value of that serial_number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT
numero_serie,
(
    select top 1 valor from smx_graficas
    where numero_serie=gra.numero_serie and (prueba_id = 56 or prueba_id = 59) and (valor != '9.999' and valor != '999.990')
    order by fecha desc
) as balance_izquierdo,
(
    select top 1 valor from smx_graficas
    where numero_serie=gra.numero_serie and prueba_id = 57 and (valor != '9.999' and valor != '999.990')
    order by fecha desc
) as balance_centro,(
    select top 1 valor from smx_graficas
    where numero_serie=gra.numero_serie and (prueba_id = 58 or prueba_id = 60) and (valor != '9.999' and valor != '999.990')
    order by fecha desc
) as balance_derecho,(
    select top 1 valor from smx_graficas
    where numero_serie=gra.numero_serie and prueba_id = 66 and (valor != '9.999' and valor != '999.990')
    order by fecha desc
) as balance_yugo_soldado,(
    select top 1 valor from smx_graficas
    where numero_serie=gra.numero_serie and prueba_id = 67 and (valor != '9.999' and valor != '999.990')
    order by fecha desc
) as balance_yugo_cople,(
    select top 1 replace(valor, ' pulg', '') from smx_graficas
    where numero_serie=gra.numero_serie and prueba_id = 68 and (valor != '9.999' and valor != '999.990')
    order by fecha desc
) as excentricidad FROM smx_graficas gra GROUP BY numero_serie
```

I have a table with a lot records of serial numbers but i want to get the last record not equal to 9.999 and 999.990 of each serial number

this query returns 180k of results but takes 20 seconds and i wanna know how to tune that query to be more faster

thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT * FROM smx_graficas
```

[image: original select]

and

this's the result set am looking for

[image: resultset]

Comment: By "last" you mean "most recent"? I assume, since you are sorting by fecha.

Comment: yes each serial number has different values of that test (prueba_id) but the only data that i need is the last value of that test (prueba_id) and ignoring results where valor is different to 9.999 or 999.990 i know thats a bad practice but the developer who created that table made valor as a varchar field instead of decimal field or float.
but thats why i need a resultset of each serial number and each test of that serial number

Comment: To make your code easier to read you could at least factor out common code into a `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good candidate for `row_number()` with a `cte`.

```
with cte as(
select 
    numero_serie,
    valor,
    prueba_id,
    RN = row_number() over (partition by numero_serie order by fecha  desc)
FROM smx_graficas gra 
where (valor != '9.999' and valor != '999.990')
)

select * 
from cte
where RN = 1
```

This should give you the results you need, then you can use `PIVOT()`

Comment: But when i run this the result set returns just 8 values and not the 180k of serial numbers, am going to edit my answer with a screenshot of the resultset that am lookin for thanks

Comment: sample data and expected output would be ideal @CesarBecerra

Comment: Perhaps my partition by was incorrect. Check the edit @CesarBecerra

Comment: i've already edit my post adding two screenshot one of the select * of the table and how i need to retrieve the info thanks @scsimon for your help

Comment: And as you acn see when the prueba_id is 58 and does not have value i need to replace with prueba_id 60 same for prueba_id = 56  doest have value need to retrieve prueba_id 59

Comment: @CesarBecerra the idea is to limit the data to the rows you need first, and then use your pivot logic or conditional aggregation. Or, use some reporting service.

Comment: Do you think is a good practice save the cte information into a variable table and then a select to that table to retrieve the data?

Comment: I think it's a good practice not to do a bunch of sub-queries, but yes... if this is a large table that could benefit you especially if you place an index on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two issues here. One is that you have a lot of repeated subqueries. The other is that your data has to be pivoted. Here's how I would solve those two issues. The first with a CTE, the second with SQL Server's built in PIVOT functionality:

```
;WITH CTE_SerialNums AS (
    SELECT
        numero_serie,
        CASE
            WHEN prueba_id IN (56, 59) THEN 'balance_izquierdo'
            WHEN prueba_id = 57 THEN 'balance_centro'
            WHEN prueba_id IN (58, 60) THEN 'balance_derecho'
            WHEN prueba_id = 66 THEN 'balance_yugo_soldado'
            WHEN prueba_id = 67 THEN 'balance_yugo_cople'
            WHEN prueba_id = 68 THEN 'excentricidad'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS balance_type,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                                numero_serie,
                            CASE
                                WHEN prueba_id IN (56, 59) THEN 'balance_izquierdo'
                                WHEN prueba_id = 57 THEN 'balance_centro'
                                WHEN prueba_id IN (58, 60) THEN 'balance_derecho'
                                WHEN prueba_id = 66 THEN 'balance_yugo_soldado'
                                WHEN prueba_id = 67 THEN 'balance_yugo_cople'
                                WHEN prueba_id = 68 THEN 'excentricidad'
                                ELSE NULL
                            END
                        ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS row_num,
        valor
    FROM
        smx_graficas T1
    WHERE
        T1.valor NOT IN ('9.999', '999.90')
)
SELECT
    numero_serie,
    balance_izquierdo,
    balance_centro,
    balance_derecho,
    balance_yugo_soldado,
    balance_yugo_cople,
    excentricidad
FROM
    (SELECT numero_serie, balance_type FROM CTE_SerialNums WHERE row_num = 1) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (MAX(valor) FOR balance_type IN (balance_izquierdo, balance_centro, balance_derecho, balance_yugo_soldado, balance_yugo_cople, excentricidad) AS PivotTable
```

I can't test this, so if I've made some kind of syntax mistake or typo, please let me know.

Comment: there a error found on line 42 with near the keyword 'AS' if i only execute the cte alone there and error on line 30 where ) close

Comment: SORRY, i didnt read the whole code now i fixed and its amazing, just takes 2 seconds thank you @Tom H